# javascript input value (html provided)

Tags: javascript

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" size="25"/>
<br/>
<button id="bu1">But 1</button>
<br/>
<button id="bu2">But 2</button>
<br/>
<button id="bu3">But 3</button>
<br/>
<button id="bu4">But 4</button>
<br/>
<button id="bu5">But 5</button>
<br/>
```

What I have done wrong to get the input value?

I have placed it in a variable and called it later on, what I want is that whatever is written in the textbox, if I press bu1, it should store the input, e.g. if "lol" is written and b4 is pressed, the "lol" input value should be placed in b4 and replace the string "But 4" to "lol" instead.
 I have not implemented the changing string to the input written, how would I do this?

```
function click()                                        
{                                       
  var textVal = document.getElementById("textbox").value;                                       
  if (this.id == onclick)                                       
  {                                     
    document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML = (textVal);                                     
  }                                     
}                                       
document.getElementById("b1").onclick = click;                                      
document.getElementById("b2").onclick = click;                                      
document.getElementById("b3").onclick = click;                                      
document.getElementById("b4").onclick = click;                                      
document.getElementById("b5").onclick = click;
```

Comment: `this.id == onclick` <-- makes no sense What is `onclick` ?

Comment: this.id is in the function, it gets called out later on the document.get.... = click;, which is the function, "this.id" calls an id, therefore, first line "this.id" = b1 and .onclick is when the button is clicked.

Comment: but the `onclick` in the if is just some random variable that is not defined. It has nothing to do with the event listener... Unless you have something like `var onclick = "b1"` defined somewhere, you got an error in your console.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad

Comment: For your changing string function - we can help to debug it if you write and give output/attempts here.  Unfortunately we can't write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your code:

- Your buttons have IDs starting with `bu` but you have omitted the `u` in your JavaScript selectors (`b1` v.s. `bu1`).
- `this.id` will never equal `onclick`, because **[`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)** is a property, and you're not referencing any element; instead, you're referencing an undefined variable.

Also, in order to update the buttons, you don't need to worry about `document.getElementById(this.id)`, and can just update the `.innerHTML` of `this` directly. You also don't need the brackets around `textVal`:

```js
function click() {
  var textVal = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
  this.innerHTML = textVal;
}

document.getElementById("bu1").onclick = click;
document.getElementById("bu2").onclick = click;
document.getElementById("bu3").onclick = click;
document.getElementById("bu4").onclick = click;
document.getElementById("bu5").onclick = click;
```

```html
<input id="textbox" type="text" size="25" />
<br/>
<button id="bu1">But 1</button>
<br/>
<button id="bu2">But 2</button>
<br/>
<button id="bu3">But 3</button>
<br/>
<button id="bu4">But 4</button>
<br/>
<button id="bu5">But 5</button>
<br/>
```

---

#### Update

Note that you can loop over all of the assignments by targeting **[`document.getElementsByTagName('button')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)**, and then accessing the current iteration of the loop with `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[i]`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
function click() {
  var textVal = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
  this.innerHTML = textVal;
}

var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('button')[i].onclick = click;
}
```

```html
<input id="textbox" type="text" size="25" />
<br/>
<button id="bu1">But 1</button>
<br/>
<button id="bu2">But 2</button>
<br/>
<button id="bu3">But 3</button>
<br/>
<button id="bu4">But 4</button>
<br/>
<button id="bu5">But 5</button>
<br/>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Wow you did it so simple, thank you. Is there a way to make a loop for the bu"1", bu"2", because  if I have 99 buttons, it would be a drag to write it out multiple times? Sorry, I am just learning and confused

Comment: @davyJ -- No problems! And that's absolutely possible :) I've just updated my answer to showcase this looped :)